# Facebook App - Share link is missing while posting to user's feed

Tags: facebook

I'm sharing a link on a user's feed - everything seems to be valid, but there's no Share link (Share button)... What is it that I'm doing wrong?

```
try {
  $su = $facebook->api(
                    "/{$uid}/feed",
                    "post",
                    array(
                      "access_token"=> $access_token,
                      "message"=> "Message",
                      "link" => "http://url",
                      "picture"=> "http://url"
                    );
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
  print_r($e);
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Doori Bar

Comment: This happens for me, too.  One interesting thing is that it works fine (the "share" link is present) when the story is just text.  When the story is more than just text - if it includes a photo, video, or link, for example - then the "share" link is missing.  Have you made any other progress on this?  I'm inclined to think it's a Facebook bug, but it seems to have been this way for years...

Answer (score 1):

very strange. I have the same problem. I have developed a Facebook App and I used a function to post on the user wall. But on the user Wall there is no "Share" link. It's only possible to like or comment it.

If I use this other technique, a dialog showing to post (on wall) OR to "send as a message instead" is displayed. (I was looking for this feature as well).

And the good thing is that the resulting post to the wall can be liked, commented AND Shared.

This is the javascript code that can help you to obtain this functionality:

```
<script>function fbs_click() {u=location.href;t=document.title;window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');return false;}</script><a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<;;url>" onclick="return fbs_click()" target="_blank">Share on Facebook</a>
```

Taken from http://askville.amazon.com/add-Share-Facebook-button-webpage/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=1539369

Hope this helps. It helped me at least ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own "Share" link using Actions described in the graph API here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

for example as json: {"name":"Share", "link":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/share.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fvisibli.com"}

Note: the url param u must be url encoded.

Comment: But this doesn't re-share the original *story*, this just shares some arbitrary link.  Correct?

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly confident this is a bug.  To encourage Facebook to fix this issue, please "vote" for this bug by adding your app as a "repro" at the following link:

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/154484061346461?browse=search_4f903d2ea60569f93022163

UPDATE:
Facebook marked the previous bug report as "Fixed" but it is NOT fixed.  Please vote for the new bug:

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/252491528185120

Comment: This *was* a bug, and has apparently been fixed by FB now.  I'll leave this answer here to point users to the FB page for legacy purposes.

Comment: UPDATE: This has NOT been fixed.  New bug: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/252491528185120

Comment: UPDATE (#2): I believe this has now, finally been fixed.